# Get ID of newly created SHEET (tab) using Google Sheets API in PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've seen tons of code about how to create a new sheet (tab) inside an existing spreadsheet. I have this working with my code below. The problem is retrieving the sheetID of what I just created.

```
$var1='xxxxxxx'  ///this is my existing spreadsheetID
try {
    $body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(array(
        'requests' => array(
            'addSheet' => array(
                'properties' => array(
                    'title' => 'aaNew ddds'
                )
            )
        )
    ));
    $results = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate(trim($var1),$body, [
            'fields' => 'spreadsheetId']);

//grabbing spreadsheetID just to prove this is working
$spreadsheetId=sprintf($results->spreadsheetId);
echo "spreadsheetId: ". $spreadsheetId;

//this will output the entire response
$responsetest = $service->spreadsheets->get(trim($var1));
echo '<pre>', var_export($responsetest, true), '</pre>', "\n";
} 
catch(Exception $ignore) {}
```

I cannot figure out how to grab the sheetID of what I just created. I know I can add more variables in fields but I still cannot get the sheetID.

It tried

```
'fields' => 'sheets(properties(sheetID))'
```

but it doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the sheet ID of the inserted sheet with your script.

In your script, the value of `fields` is fixed as `spreadsheetId`. But, the property of inserted sheet is returned in `replies` fields. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
$results = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate(trim($var1),$body, [
            'fields' => 'spreadsheetId']);
```

#### To:

```
$results = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate(trim($var1), $body, [
  "fields" => "spreadsheetId,replies",
]);

$sheetId = $results["replies"][0]["addSheet"]["properties"]["sheetId"];
```

or

```
$sheetId = $results->getReplies()[0]->getAddSheet()->getProperties()->getSheetId();
```

or

```
$sheetId = $results->replies[0]->addSheet->properties->sheetId;
```

- By this modification, you can retrieve the sheet ID of the inserted sheet with your script.
- I think that in this case, you can use `$results = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate(trim($var1), $body);` instead of `$results = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate(trim($var1), $body, ["fields" => "spreadsheetId,replies"]);`. Because as the default, `replies` is returned.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)